# iPhone dev view swapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I'm trying to find out the best way to swap views for an iPhone game I'm making.  I have a "root view controller" that has a reference to all the view controllers I want to swap between.  So I add the main menu view to this root view controller - [self.view addSubview:mainMenuController.view]; - Then in the main menu view I have an instructions button.  I define an IBAction in the mainMenuController to respond to the instructions button being clicked.  From there, I call [self.view removeFromSuperview] which works great.  It gets rid of the main menu.  So next I want to add the instructions view.  I figured that it would be as simple as [super.view addSubview:super.instructionsController.view], but no luck!  I've thought of a few ways to get around this, but they all seem very inelegant, as I would like to keep all references to my view controllers in one place, the root view controller.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I just got around it by setting a delegate property in each of my controllers to the root view controller.

Answer (score -1):

This seemed like a straight forward question, but it took me a while to sort out what I think wasn't working.

(If Xcode was giving you an error, or simply misbehaving, it would have been useful to add to the question...)

But the gist of it is, I think you think of the views as being a number of resources that can get stuck the ViewControllers, but the relationship is a little more structured.

This is discussed in -> [Is it possible to add the same view to two different view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903212/is-it-possible-to-add-the-same-view-to-two-different-view-controllers)

So, I think this line is where things break down. The parameter is a reference to a UIView object, but the actual View Controller and View management will breakdown.

[super.view addSubview:super.instructionsController.view]

[Is it possible to add the same view to two different view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903212/is-it-possible-to-add-the-same-view-to-two-different-view-controllers)