# Is it possible to add the same view to two different view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, swift4

I get the following error message:

> A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a
>   time!

Is it possible to add the same view to two different view controllers?

I want to add one instance of a Google Map to a Tab View Controller.

I'm using swift4 with the storyboards.

Comment: You can create a xib file of the common view and add it to as many controllers you want.

Comment: I'm using swift4 with the storyboard - and for every controller I add - I also get a new instance of the view.

Comment: Of course. A new instance of the view will be created every time you add it to a controller. What do you want I don’t understand. Please state your requirement clearly.

Comment: I'm working with the mapView from the Google Maps iOS SDK. And I want only one instance of the mapView in my Tab View Controller. Such that you see the same instance of the map in different tabs.

Comment: create a .XIB and you can use it in as many viewControllers as needed, you should do the research into .XIBs as they are super handy for certain things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were a typical view then you should create an XIB and add a new instance of it to each view.
Since you're using GMSMapView from the Google Maps SDK, and you want to have the same instance across multiple tabs the approach will be different.

You can either:

1. **New Instance, Same Parameters**: 
   Create a new instance in each tab with the parameters set to be the same as the other tabs.
2. **Move Around the Single Instance**:
   Create an instance of GMSMapView. Store it in a shared property. Use  `addSubview()` to move it around. Basically use `addSubview()` in the new tab to remove it from the old one and add it to the new one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your second suggestion is exactly what I want to do. If I execute `addSubview()` will the `GMSMapView` be detached from the previous Tab?

Comment: That's the beauty of it, Cocoa doesn't support having the same `UIView` in multiple places so `addSubview()` will automatically remove it from it's previous location and add it to the new one.
I used something similar for YouTube Video View. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A `UIView` can only be associated with one other view, because it can only have one parent view, which is set as the `superView` property. Also things like layout are set on this view and are relative to it's superview, so it makes no sense to use the same view in multiple Controllers.
The best solution would be to subclass `UIView` and then add new instances of your custom class to every ViewController